# Use of 'the' before human voice

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Which is correct?

> - The fascinating features of human voice
>
>   *OR*
> - The fascinating features of the human voice

Is there a rule or is it another difference between American and British English? We always use 'the' for the human brain. How about in this case, 'human voice'? By the way, this example comes from an academic paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

1. I can hear **a human voice.**
2. I can hear **the human voice.**
3. I can hear **human voice(s).**

In #1, I can hear a voice which belongs to some individual person, and is not the voice or call of any other kind of animal. In #2, I'm stating that I have the ability to hear the voices of humans in general. In #3, I find myself hearing the sound of some human voice, from one or more people, as I might *hear wind* or *smell food.*

In this last sense, *human voice* is like *bird song:* it's sort of an abstract substance. Say I go into a cafeteria, where I'm surrounded by the sound of *voice,* then I hear *a voice* and turn around to see my friend calling me, whereupon I sit with him and we discuss my research of *the voice.*

If you want to make general statements about the vocal abilities of humans, use *the human voice*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: (1) “If you want to make general statements about the vocal abilities of humans, use the human voice.” – Isn’t it like in a certain context the definite article can also be applied to only one voice, especially when that one voice has already been mentioned several times earlier and is not a new thing for the listener/reader? Like, for example, in this passage (please disregard my broken English in it – my main purpose was just to provided the context): “On a remote planet, where

Comment: @Jon Purdy: (2) only terrible monsters could make themselves homes there once lived three terrible monsters: Danny, Gummy and Papaya. They all lived in their caves – each one in his own cave – all three caves being inside of one mountain. Danny was the bravest among all of them. One day he decided to explore a mountain that was located not far away from the place where they lived. It turned out that there was also a big cave in that mountain, but no one lived in it. Danny was proud to

Comment: @Jon Purdy: (3) inform Gummy and Papaya of a new cave that he had found. Three monsters began to visit that cave frequently even though no one lived in there. The cave was quite big and they all liked it. One day, however, something strange happened – Danny reported hearing a human voice inside of that cave. Gummy and Papaya did not believe him – they thought he was just trying to scare them. Three days later, however, Gummy also heard a human voice in that cave. When he described it to Danny, they both realized that it

Comment: @Jon Purdy: (4) was the same voice. Now both Danny and Gummy stopped going to that cave as they were afraid of that strange human voice that they heard. Papaya told them that he did not believe either of them, but secretly he was envying them. “How come they have this ability to hear something that I can’t hear?” – Papaya would think to himself. He felt extremely upset about it and even began to look down on himself. One day, however, while entering that spooky cave, he suddenly heard a strange voice. He knew for sure it was a human voice and he also knew it was exactly

Comment: @Jon Purdy: (5) that voice that Danny and Gummy had heard before – it fully checked out with their descriptions. On one hand, Papaya was scared, but on the other hand, he was glad to know that he also had the ability that the other two monsters had. He quickly rushed back to their caves. “What happened”, asked Danny when he saw Papaya running up to them. “I can hear the human voice now!” – shouted Papaya.” Do you think the last sentence here would also be okay (in this particular context)?

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Great answer. You could perhaps clarify that the definite article is also used to describe a class or category of something. "The tiger in the garden is eating my roses." vs. "The tiger is an almost-extinct species of animal."

Comment: @brilliant: Yes, it's correct, though redundant: the fact that the voice is *human* has already been mentioned, so you can say just "I can hear the voice now!"

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Is there any difference between "I can hear the human voice" and "I can hear the human voices"? (the latter one could serve as the fourth possible case in your answer)

Comment: @brilliant: You'd say "the human voices" in a situation where you need to draw a distinction between human voices and some other voices. Say there's a bunch of humans and aliens in a room, and the humans are much louder: "The human voices drowned out the alien ones".

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I see, thank you. I think it would be good if you added this one to your answer too. It's funny how little the official textbooks explain things about the usage of definite and indefinite articles in English. English learners often remain "numb" toward these slight, yet very meaningful differences.

Comment: @Rhodri: Yeah, it was a tough thing for me to reason through, as the distinctions are subtle no matter what, so I may have explained some things a bit oddly, but this is my best explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

To me, there seems to be a subtle difference in the meaning.

Without the word "the", the phrase seems to be comparing or contrasting the human voice to something else (i.e. "The fascinating features of human voice *as opposed to whale sounds*...

Using the word "the", the phrase seems to stand on its own.